# What technology stack to pair with a Netbeans Platform client?

Tags: netbeans-platform

In a typical client/server application, the client needs to be implemented with a RCP, which happens to be Netbeans Platform in this case. There will be 2 scenarios of data access in the application:

1. Business object centric: relations between business objects need to be maintained, using something like JPA.
2. Data centric: data is loaded in a table, and all manipulation to the data is done within the table.

I am wondering what's the right technology/framework stack to choose for the above scenarios. Also any suggestion on how a NBP client communicates with the server?

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about a standard 3 tier architecture.

The normal approach is to use an Application Server as the backend, which in turn interacts with your database.

When dealing with this scenario the solution that I found the easiest to implement was RESTful communications from the Netbeans-Client to the Application Server, and then JPA to manipulate the data in the database.